# Will my Avocado plant survive having the stem bit off by a raccoon?

Tags: plant-care, avocado, raccoons

I have 2 avocado plants - grown from pits, indoors and just a year old. With the weather getting better, I moved them outside in their containers. It has been a week and they are outside day and night and sprouted new leaves too.

To my utter shock last week, I found one of the plants totally cut off at the stem. Just the pit and roots remain in the pot now. And I saw a raccoon this morning roaming near my garden bed so most likely it is the work of this raccoon. most of my seedings have been plucked out of earth or bit off at the stem.

I am most concerned for my avocado though. Both the plants are a year old, grown indoors and mean a lot to me. So my question to the avocado experts is this - will my avocado regrow (the entire stem that grew from the pit - roughly a foot long, has been bitten off)? Or should I consider it dead?
Looking forward to all your comments.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe bring both of them back indoors until you can make a protective screen from some 1/2 inch/ 1.3cm square mesh and can firmly anchor it. The nibblings could have been from something other than mentioned, or from more than one type of nibbler; a perimeter fence of 1/2 inch/ 1.3cm square mesh and 1meter/ 3ft tall may help for anything that can't climb/ jump over it; And if they can jump/ climb over it, then there also needs to be the same mesh firmly fastened over the top of it!

The mesh needs to be small enough and rigid enough to protect from them reaching through it to your Avocado trees, and also to protect from smaller nibblers. With good care,. your seedling might sprout again and survive!